# парсинг excel файла

Tags: excel, uwp, visual-basic

Перейду сразу к делу, у меня есть excel файл(формат xls,если это вдруг важно) в котором хранится расписание занятий групп на неделю. Как мне вытащить из файла данные о расписании определенной группы? Для universal windows platform не нашел решения(
Не могу понять алгоритм(никогда раньше таким не занимался), если бы кто наставил на путь истинный, то был бы очень признателен.Заранее спасибо!))

Comment: *VBA* не хотите?

Comment: в каком смысле?

Comment: xlsx основан на OfficeOpenXML формате данных. Так что открываете файл и парсите по формату :) готовые либы есть, гуглятся по "c++ xlsx parser", например: https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt . Файл разбирается довольно просто, открыли, получили количество листов, нашли нужный лист, пробежались по ячейкам, нашли нужное. Если формат расписания фиксированный, т.е. вам надо достать значение ячейки C5 листа 1, то довольно тривиально :)

Comment: @sleepsomewhile, в смысле код на *VBA*, в самом *Excel*

Comment: мне нужно в программе задать группу и вывести ее расписание

Comment: @goldstar_labs забыл сказать , то пишу на visual basic)

Comment: @sleepsomewhile почему тогда в тегах с++?

Comment: @goldstar_labs  я и на vb и на c++ читаю, но пишу на vb,это если есть примеры на c++

Comment: @goldstar_labs просто c++ популярнее, соответственно примеров больше

Comment: @goldstar_labs а что там с макросами? Как можно через них реализовывать?

Comment: @sleepsomewhile с макросами не ко мне)